# "Required fields are missing" I got this warning even the value in that field is not missing

Tags: lookup, required-field

Required fields are missing warning when I'm saving the record on a lookup field and can't be saved but it has the value that it required
(FinServ__PrimaryOwner__c is the API name of the Primary Owner field)
I'm very new to salesforce and never found this problem before
Thank you for your help in advance:)[image]

Comment: Check if this is being set t null from before triggers or flows.

Comment: What @NagendraSingh has mentioned is likely. Another possibility could be a field with the same name but a different API. Check fields/ page layout for duplicate fields.

Comment: Thank you I will tell my team about this:)